# Getting a div scroll position using javascript.

Tags: javascript, scroll

I have one button in a div tag. That div tag also has a vertical scroll bar.

If I scroll that bar and click on the button which is inside that div, it should return the scroll position as an alert message.

How to do that using JavaScript?

Comment: You could do this pretty easily with jquery. Is that an option?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [retrieve Scrollbar position with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481350/retrieve-scrollbar-position-with-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

The `scrollTop` property tells you the vertical scroll position:

```
document.getElementById("yourButton").onclick = function() {
   alert(document.getElementById("yourDiv").scrollTop); 
}
```