# How to get and set TChromium scrollbar positions?

Tags: delphi, chromium, tchromium, chromium-embedded

How to get and set `TChromium` scrollbar positions in Delphi ?

Comment: Voted to reopen. This is in my view a valid and useful question! There's not much to research (so not much to show as well), since it's probably impossible to get or set scrollbar positions in CEF.

Comment: Thank you for answer, I will try to another solution.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible to work with javascript objects directly. Just use CefV8Context of the frame.

Here is an example:

```
var
    val: ICefV8Value;
    context: ICefv8Context;
    excp: ICefV8Exception;
    scroll: TPoint;
begin
    if (Chromium1.Browser.MainFrame = nil) then
      exit;

    //this will work only with exact frame
    context := Chromium1.Browser.MainFrame.GetV8Context;

    if (context <> nil) then
    begin
        context.Eval('window.pageXOffset', val, excp);
        scroll.x := val.GetIntValue;
        context.Eval('window.pageYOffset', val, excp);
        scroll.y := val.GetIntValue;
    end
    else
      exit;

    //todo: do something with scroll here
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently playing with [CefSharp](https://github.com/chillitom/CefSharp), I do think that this is similar than in Delphi. Here is my solution:

```cs
public int GetVerticalScrollPosition()
{
    var r = _webView.EvaluateScript(@"document.body.scrollTop");
    return Convert.ToInt32(r);
}

public void SetVerticalScrollPosition(int pos)
{
    _webView.ExecuteScript(
        string.Format(@"document.body.scrollTop = {0}", pos));
}
```

I'm not that Delphi expert anymore, hope you can understand my code; basically [I use JavaScript to read/write the scroll positions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481350/retrieve-scrollbar-position-with-javascript) and execute these small JavaScript snippets through the `EvaluateScript` and `ExecuteScript` methods.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JavaScript in TCromium.Browser. That's the easiest way:

```
Chromium1.Browser.MainFrame.ExecuteJavaScript('window.scrollBy(0,50)', 'about:blank', 0);
```

Good luck!