# Alert to give scrollbar top location (scroll top) not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the scrollTop value on scroll. In other words, the location of the scrollbar at a certain point in the page.

Why isn't this working?

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    alert($(document).scrollTop());
});
```

It is wrapped in `$(document).ready(...`

Comment: Are you sure that the `document` is indeed the element scrolling and not a `body` or `div` element?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481350/retrieve-scrollbar-position-with-javascript

Comment: i have. I am using it and the rest is working. no script errors.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "not working".

Comment: @PalashMondal There are not alerts on scroll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will only trigger when you change the scroll bar.

http://jsfiddle.net/UtL2N/

```
Same code as OP
```

Comment: it doesn't though work though. I am scroll and nothing is happening.

Comment: weird, when I moved it out of the document.ready as in your jsfiddle, it worked.

Comment: Maybe there is an error in the document ready function that is preventing the whole function from running.

Comment: maybe, but all the other jquery / javascript inside the document ready function is working fine.