# Angular check when an element is in view

Tags: angular

In angular, how do I detect if a certain element is in view?

For example, I have the following:

```
<div class="test">Test</div>
```

Is there a way to detect when this div is in view?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tell if a DOM element is visible in the current viewport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport)

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7557433/1009922).

Comment: Inject *$element* in your constructor like this: `@Inject('$element') private readonly $element,`. then:  `var isVisible = this.$element.find('div').is(':visible') ? true : false;`

Comment: @ConnorsFan I think his asking about the 'angular' way of doing so, probably an angular directive without having to use custom javascript code. For that extent, I think this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52643937/1833622 answers the question.

Answer (score 16):

Based off this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22480938/3367818), adapted to Angular:

Template:

```
<div #testDiv class="test">Test</div>
```

Component:

```
  @ViewChild('testDiv', {static: false}) private testDiv: ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>;
  isTestDivScrolledIntoView: boolean;

  @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
  isScrolledIntoView(){
    if (this.testDiv){
      const rect = this.testDiv.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
      const topShown = rect.top >= 0;
      const bottomShown = rect.bottom <= window.innerHeight;
      this.isTestDivScrolledIntoView = topShown && bottomShown;
    }
  }
```

[Example with scroll event binding](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fgxghc?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Another nice feature is to determine how much of that `<div>` is to be considered as "within view". [Here's a reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51121566/3367818) to such implementation.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a directive that you can use. It uses the shiny [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) API

### The directive

```js
import {AfterViewInit, Directive, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef} from '@angular/core'

@Directive({
  selector: '[isVisible]',
})

/**
 * IS VISIBLE DIRECTIVE
 * --------------------
 * Mounts a component whenever it is visible to the user
 * Usage: <div *isVisible>I'm on screen!</div>
 */
export class IsVisible implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private vcRef: ViewContainerRef, private tplRef: TemplateRef<any>) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const observedElement = this.vcRef.element.nativeElement.parentElement

    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(([entry]) => {
      this.renderContents(entry.isIntersecting)
    })
    observer.observe(observedElement)
  }

  renderContents(isIntersecting: boolean) {

    this.vcRef.clear()

    if (isIntersecting) {
      this.vcRef.createEmbeddedView(this.tplRef)
    }
  }
}
```

### Usage

```html
<div *isVisible>I'm on screen!</div>
```

Comment: const observedElement = this.vcRef.element.nativeElement.parentElement
does this mean it mounts whenever the parent is visible? so if our parent is the entire page, it will always be considered visible, in that case, i put a div container around the component to make it more localised.

Comment: You should handle ngOnDestroy here to cleanup when you are done..

Answer (score 3):

I had the same task in one of the latest projects I've worked on and ended up using a npm package, which provides a working directive out of the box. So if someone doesn't feel like writing and testing directives, like me, check out this npm package [ng-in-view](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-in-viewport). It works like a charm in Angular 14. 
I hope that this post will help someone to save some time writing directives.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating a slightly vanilla directive (though it uses the `@HostListener` decorator and stuff). If the height of the directive-bound element is fully within the viewport, it emits a boolean value (`$event`) of `true`, otherwise it returns `false`. It does this through JS `getBoundingClientRect()` method; where it can then take the rect element's position and do some quick/simple math with the viewport's height against the top/bottom position of the element.

`inside-viewport.directive.ts`:

```js
import { Directive, ElementRef, EventEmitter, HostListener, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[insideViewport]'
})
export class InsideViewportDirective {
  @Output() insideViewport = new EventEmitter();
  constructor(
    private elementRef: ElementRef;
  ) { }

  @HostListener('body:scroll', ['$event'])
  public onScrollBy(): any {
    const windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    const boundedRect = this.elementRef.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();

    if (boundedRect.top >= 0 && boundedRect.bottom <= windowHeight) {
      this.insideViewport.emit(true);
    } else {
      this.insideViewport.emit(false);
    }
  }
}
```

Then, in the template `app.component.html`, I added an additional second argument (`string`), to follow the first `$event` arg (which emits the boolean value) so that the component could identify *which* element was scrolled into view, given that you can apply this directive to multiple elements:

```html
<div (insideViewport)="onElementView($event, 'blockOne')">
  <span *ngIf="showsText"> I'm in view! </span>
</div>
```

And in the component (aka the "do stuff" part) `app.component.ts`, now we can receive the boolean value to drive the behavior of the conditional component property; while also qualifying the element as the first block (aka `blockOne`) in a view that might have multiple "blocks":

```js
// ... other code
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  showsText!: boolean;

  //... other code

  onElementView(value: any, targetString: string): void {
    if (value === true && targetString === 'blockOne') {
      this.showsText = true;
    } else { this.showsText = false; }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps as I've been trying to figure the most vanilla-y way to do this (with core angular stuff) for a while lol -- but I am not nearly versed enough on best-case APIs *sadface*

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68484378/9566462 has a bug, here is a corrected version

Use like

```html
<div appIsOnScreen #isOnScreen="isOnScreen">123</div>
{{ isOnScreen.isOnScreen$ | async }}
```

Directive

```js
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { defer, Observable, shareReplay } from 'rxjs';

@Directive({
  exportAs: 'isOnScreen',
  selector: '[appIsOnScreen]',
  standalone: true,
})
export class IsOnScreenDirective {
  public readonly isOnScreen$: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor(private readonly _elementRef: ElementRef) {
    this.isOnScreen$ = defer(() => {
      return this.getIsOnScreen$(this._elementRef.nativeElement);
    }).pipe(
      shareReplay({
        bufferSize: 1,
        refCount: true,
      }),
    );
  }

  private getIsOnScreen$(element: Element): Observable<boolean> {
    return new Observable<boolean>((subscriber) => {
      const intersectionObserver = new IntersectionObserver(
        (entries) => {
          // Sometimes entries receive multiple entries
          // Last one is correct
          subscriber.next(entries[entries.length - 1].isIntersecting);
        },
        {
          threshold: 1,
        },
      );

      intersectionObserver.observe(element);

      return () => {
        intersectionObserver.disconnect();
      };
    });
  }
}
```