# Angular custom element in view

Tags: angular, view

I have the following:

**main.module.ts**

```
//Importing "my_section"
...
import { my_section } from './my_section';

@NgModule({
   declarations: [...],
   imports: [..., my_section],
   exports: [...]
})
export class main_pageModule {}
```

**main.html**

```
 //As an example, let say I have three "my_section"
<div class="top">
    <my_section></my_section>
    <my_section></my_section>
    <my_section></my_section>
</div>
```

Then,

**my_section.ts**

```
...
@Component({
  selector: 'my_section',
  templateUrl: 'my_section.html'
})

export class my_section{
 ...
}
```

---

This is a simplified version of it: As you can see, `<my_section></my_section>` is imported from `my_section.ts` into `main.module.ts`.

I am trying to trigger a function when each `<my_section></my_section>` is in view.

I tried to use `ViewChild`, but no luck.

Any idea how I can detect when a custom element is in view?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular check when an element is in view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49215634/angular-check-when-an-element-is-in-view)

Comment: DId you try using `getBoundingClientRect` ? Or IntersectionObserver API? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [`ViewChildren`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren) decorator in your component (not in module as in your example):

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, QueryList, ViewChildren } from '@angular/core';
import { my_section } from './my_section';

...

class <YOUR_COMPONENT_NAME> implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChildren(my_section) mySections: QueryList<my_section>;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // mySections are set at this stage

    // you may listen to mySections change
    this.mySections.changes.subscribe(section => {    
      // section is available
    });

    // or just iterate over available sections
    this.mySections.forEach(section => {    
      // section is available
    });
  }
}
```