# What is the purpose of +- on a Javascript number?

Tags: javascript

I came across some code recently that was like this:

```
const element = document.getElementById("myId")
const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect()

const height = +-(rect.height / 1)
```

First of all, what is the deal with the division by 1? And second, what does `+-` do?

I put that logic into a Fiddle and it appears that it flips the sign of whatever is in the parentheses (from positive to negative and from negative to positive). However, if I wanted to flip a sign, why wouldn't I just do `-(myvariable)`?

Regarding the division by 1, it appears that the type of `rect.height` is already a number with floating-point precision and the divide operator is also floating-point division so we're not trying to generate an int or anything.

I just need some help trying to understand what that's trying to do.

Edit: The code was found here: [Check if element is partially in viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30943662/check-if-element-is-partially-in-viewport#comment118123546_51121566)

Comment: Where exactly did you find that code?

Comment: [Check this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30943662/check-if-element-is-partially-in-viewport#comment118123546_51121566)

Comment: Modified original post.

Comment: `+-(null / 1);` creates `-0`

Comment: Often I find in javascript code people use `(+"string")` to cast to a number, similarly for `-` and `/` --- so the user here may have just ... used them all.

Comment: That linked answer should just be edited so it uses just `-rect.height`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [division `/`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Division) will implicitly convert both operands to numbers:

```js
const str = "10.5"

const division = str / 1;

console.log(division);
console.log(typeof division);
```

Using [a unary minus `-`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_negation) will implicitly convert the operand *and* change its sign:

```js
const str = "10.5";
const minusStr = -str;

console.log(minusStr);
console.log(typeof minusStr);


const negativeNum = -3;
const minusNegativeNum = -negativeNum;

console.log(minusNegativeNum);
```

Using [a unary plus `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus) will *convert* anything to a number. If supplied with a number, it leaves it as it is:

```js
const str = "10.5";
const plusStr = +str;

console.log(plusStr);
console.log(typeof plusStr);


const negativeNum = -3;
const plusNegativeNum = +negativeNum;

console.log(plusNegativeNum);
```

The above is also the order of how the expression `+-(rect.height / 1)` would be evaluated.

So, what does `+-(rect.height / 1)` do? The same as `-rect.height` but tacks on two useless operators.

It should be noted, that none of the conversions are really needed - not because a unary minus already does it, but because [the `height` property produces a number anyway](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMRectReadOnly/height):

```js
const element = document.getElementById("myId")
const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect()

console.log(rect.height);
console.log(typeof rect.height);

const height = +-(rect.height / 1);
console.log(height);
```

```css
#myId {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="myId"></div>
```

So the whole expression just gets the height and inverts its sign.

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide the link where you found this code?
But from what you provided, I would agree with you. The `+` operator and the dividing by one wouldn't do anything. So I would say that it's a typo, bit of temporary code, or the developer having one too many drinks.

Comment: "*or the developer having one too many drinks*" maybe we've just not had enough drinks to appreciate it. :P

Answer (score 0):

I think it´s a trap. I´m not shure but if you get numbers from document you get strings instead of numbers. this + before a number in a string (example "10") would turn it in type number.

For example

```
"11" + 1 = "111"
```

because javascript concanate this as 2 strings.
but

```
var a = "11"
+a makes it = 11
```

but the restit sadly out of context i think

Edit:

ah okay.

```
  Math.floor(100 - (((rect.top >= 0 ? 0 : rect.top) / +-(rect.height / 1)) * 100)) < percentVisible

+-(rect.height / 1)) * 100
```

I think this parts makes this number to a percent value.JS don´t know percent. Everything is value / 100, but to get the right value, you should value / 1.