# Get scroll position in Javascript

Tags: javascript, scroll, cross-browser

I would like to retrieve the current scroll position in Javascript, after some research I found this: `window.scrollY` and `window.scollTop`.

But the problem is that it does not work 100% on all browsers, is there something more reliable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [retrieve Scrollbar position with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481350/retrieve-scrollbar-position-with-javascript)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The solution for JavaScript is:

```
var scrollPos = window.scrollY || window.scrollTop || document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].scrollTop;
```

Or if you use jQuery (this is more reliable, due cross-browser support):

```
var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
```

Answer (score 11):

> For cross-browser compatibility, use `window.pageYOffset`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/pageYOffset