# Hide icon with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have

```
<img class="arrow_down" src="arrow_down.png" alt="scroll down" style="max-width: 5%; height: auto;">
```

Now, I want that image **visible**, until I scroll down the webpage, so **from the first scroll it will be hidden**. I code it in java-script or jQuery like this:

```
jQuery(function($, undefined) {
  if ($("body").scrollTop() = 0 || $("html").scrollTop() = 0) {
            $(".arrow_down").fadeIn(400);
        }

        else {
            $(".arrow_down").hide();
        }

    };
```

This doesn't work, please help me...

Comment: what is your expected result? can you give a better description?

Comment: Yes, of course..I land on my page, there is right at landing an arrow facing down (for users to know that they should scroll down, its called UX or UI), no, Because of some weird responsive problems, I want to make that icon(arrow_down) hidden, right when the user starts scrolling down... do You catch It?? :) @Rejith R Krishnan

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am not understanding what is missing in my answer.

Comment: Your answer is great... THANKS!!! but I just dont know how to... start the code.. please write me whole code... because just:

jQuery(window).on('scroll', function() {
  jQuery('.arrow_down').hide();
});

itselve doesnt work

Comment: That **is** *the* whole code. You just need to make sure that you have jQuery included.

Comment: How I sayd, check my website: http://david.addagio.cz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$(function () {
  $('.arrow_down').hide();
  var curScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if (curScroll < $(window).scrollTop())
      $('.arrow_down').show();
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0)
      $('.arrow_down').hide();
    curScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  });
});
```

What happens here is, when the scrolling is done, the script checks if the scroll has been done down or up. If the scroll has been only down, then it shows the down arrow.

Comment: You shouldn't set the `scroll` event inside the `ready` event handler, and definetivelly not using `.on()`. Use `.bind('scroll')` or `.scroll()`

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel why so?

Comment: Because the `.on()` event will try to find a 'common parent' to add the event handler to. And the parent of the `window` is `window`. So, unnecessary work. And then, everytime the `scroll` event is triggered, jQuery verifies if this is the object that is the target of the event, which is bad because that kind of event is triggered hundreds of times. That won't happen using `.bind()`.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Sorry buddy. Corrected it. Thanks for the insight. `:)`

Comment: You're welcome. I would be extremelly careful with that  `curScroll`. It currently had no `var`, which makes it a global variable, completelly free to be edited and ruined by anyone willing to play with your script. At the very least, I would add a `var` to it.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Added it. `:)`

Comment: @PetrCihlar What exactly would you like to happen and what doesn't work?

Comment: Now it looks better! One thing you can try is to use `document.documentElement.scrollTop` instead of `$(window).scrollTop()`. This was based on http://stackoverflow.com/a/2481776/2729937 which has a cross-browser way to get the scroll position. But I would leave it as an exercise to the O.P.

Comment: OK, now... I will show You my website, that I am doing it for.. You can check what I am doing bad... and why it doesnt work. http://david.addagio.cz

And... the script is right at the bottom of source, and the arrow_down is that white arrow you hould see right from landing

Comment: @PetrCihlar Tell me one thing. Should it be displayed when you land on the page or not?

Comment: @PetrCihlar Can you see my edit? The second line `$('.arrow_down').hide();`.

Comment: @Praaven Kumar Yep, it should

Comment: You mean... it actually works? even without any fixes? Now?

Comment: Mybe browser? what browser R U using?

Comment: Well, it still doesnt work there... Maybe my computer.. but still BIG BIG thanks for help :)

Answer (score 3):

Bind the 'scroll' event on window to function which hides the image.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() != 0)
        jQuery('.arrow_down').hide();
    jQuery(window).on('scroll', function() {
        jQuery('.arrow_down').hide();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img class="arrow_down" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="scroll down" style="max-width: 5%; height: auto;"/>
<div style="height:500px;">&nbsp;</div>
```

If you want to show it on scroll to top again do the following.

```
jQuery(window).on('scroll', function() {
  jQuery('.arrow_down').toggle( $(this).scrollTop() == 0);
});
```

Comment: @PetrCihlar This is the right answer. You just have to make minimal changes to the event handler for it to work.

Comment: @Ismael Miguel What changes do you mean?

Comment: @PraveenKumar It seems there must be more to the question than meets the eye. `:P`

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan The O.P. wants the image to show when you scroll up again. Which is easily done. Just copy-paste the code in the handler, almost. Instead of that huge `if`, maybe using `$(window).scrollTop()` or similar would be enough.

Comment: And guys.... how to do that handler... I have no idea.. just: jQuery(window).on('scroll', function() {
  jQuery('.arrow_down').hide();
});

doesnt work alone, how to start it.. you know what i mean

Comment: @PetrCihlar make sure that the code is inside `<script></script>` tag. I think you know that, just making sure.