# delay on the mousewheel event

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousewheel

I encountered this problem that I have no idea how to search for it or explain it.
I'm trying to do add classes using mousewheel event.
I wrote this JS code

`

```
var count = 1;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).bind('mousewheel', function(e){
        if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta /120 > 0) {
           $('li.'+count).addClass("show").siblings().removeClass("show");
            count = count - 1;
            if (count == 0) {
            count = 6;
          }


        }
        else{
          $('li.'+count).addClass("show").siblings().removeClass("show");
          count++;
          if (count == 6) {
            count = 0;
          }

        }


    });});`
```

Since im looping into 5 list elements, I did those conditions ... pretty primitive code, but did the job.

The html

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li class="1 show" >
            <div class="row">
                <div class=" col-md-5">
                    <img src="img/bouchra.jpg" alt="Someone 1" >
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7 text-center">
                    <h2 style="display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;font-size:18px;">Someone 1 Someone 1</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="2" ></li>
        <li class="3" ></li>
                ...
    </ul>
```

Well this works as I wanted it to work ... I can loop through my lists and show hide them while scrolling ... But the problem is It is too fast, for every little wheel spin it changes all.
I tried to do a timeout

```
var count = 1;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).bind('mousewheel', function(e){

        if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta /120 > 0) {
            setTimeout(function() {  $('li.'+count).addClass("show").siblings().removeClass("show");
            count = count - 1;
            if (count == 0) {
            count = 6;
          }
             }, 800);

        }
        else{
        setTimeout(function() {   $('li.'+count).addClass("show").siblings().removeClass("show");
          count++;
          if (count == 6) {
            count = 0;
          }
             }, 800);
        }


    });
});
```

But it didn't work, the event doesn't work but it remembers how many spins I did and apply them after.
Im a newbie, please help ;-;

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for a *throttle*.

Setting a timeout with `setTimeout` will *delay* the action, but all the actions will eventually run. A throttle works by only accepting one function for a given amount of time.

```
var throttle = 500; // .5 seconds
var time = -1;

element.addEventListener("myEvent", function (e) {
   var now = Date.now() // Current time, in milliseconds
   if (time !== -1 && now - time < throttle)
     return; // Get out, we haven't waited long enough

   time = now;
   // This will only run on the event after at least [throttle] ms have passed
   doThing();
})
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jkrzj8tw/4/) that tries to make sense of your specific situation, though I'm not sure at all what you're going for. Play around with the `throttle` var to find what works best for you.

Please try to provide some working code in future questions with a JSFiddle or something similar!

P.S.: As I said I'm not sure what you're going for, but since `mousewheel`'s `wheelDelta` has [poor browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousewheel), I'd consider using `scroll` and [keeping track of your position on the screen manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481350/how-to-get-scrollbar-position-with-javascript).