# How to create a scroll event for specific positions

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, scroll, frontend

I currently have a scroll event which changes the background when scrolled downwards.  However, I'd like the background to revert to its original color once the page is scrolled or positioned to the top.  How do I do this?
Here is some of my code:

```
class Nav extends Component {
    state = {
        background: "skyblue",
        navSize: "130px",
        activeItem: '',
        options : [
            {key: 'logout', text: 'logout'}
        ]
    }
    handleItemClick = (e) => this.setState({activeItem: e})
    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
    } 
    componentWillUnmount() {
         window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Detecting scroll position

```
var currentPosition = 0;
var originalColor = ''; // original color before scroll down
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
  currentPosition = (document.body.getBoundingClientRect()).top;
  if ((document.body.getBoundingClientRect()).top > currentPosition ){
        // user scroll to up direction
   }
    else{
         // user scroll to down direction
     }
});
```

Now you can implement your custom logic based on scroll postion up or down.

Comment: How do I get the logic for the specific position when the scrollbar is all the way at the top of the page?

Comment: @guest229192 If this value  `(document.body.getBoundingClientRect()).top` comes out to be less then 50. consider this as a top position and handle this accordingly in the `scroll` event listener.

Answer (score 0):

could get the scroll top and based on the value, update a state.  Then based on the state, change the background-color. Heres some psuedo code to illustrate:

```
handleScroll = (target) => {
    var a = element.scrollTop;

 //separate this into a different async function/promise and call here
 //consider using Refs instead of DOM method: 
// https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

const elRef = document.getElementById(target);
    window.scrollTo({
        left: 0, 
        top: elRef.offsetTop -80,
        behavior: "smooth"
    })
  }

    if(a <= 200){
        this.setState({ posForBG: top })
    } else {
        this.setState({ posForBG: middle })
    }
}
```

then in body set the class based on the state

```
<body class={this.state.posForBG}>
    ...
```

Finally just set background color in you css, like:

```
body{
    transition: background-color .5s ease-in-out;
    .top{
        background-color: blue
    }
    .middle{
        background-color: green;
    }
}
```

Could use react-fns as well if thats easier.  Alot of what you want to do is solved already here: https://github.com/jaredpalmer/react-fns

Comment: This looks nice if only i could figure out how to do the "element.scrollTop" part

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481350/how-to-get-scrollbar-position-with-javascript

Comment: or because its on the body tag? Just set the `div.app` to be full width/height and do <div class=`${this.state.posForBG} app` >
using a string literal for the class, with backticks

Comment: set `state.posForBG` on `<App/> and use the state to handle both the App Class and the scroll-to for the specific element