# how to store user's position on the same scroll position on page refresh

Tags: javascript, browser, scroll

I want to store users location on a page.
Let's say the user is reading an article.
If the user hit the refresh button it should reload on the same position.

I know I can use `document.body.scrollTop` to store the user's location.
I want to know if there is a better way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get scrollbar position with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481350/how-to-get-scrollbar-position-with-javascript)

Comment: I don't want to get scroll bar position

Comment: Are you sure? The scroll bar position could be used to set it on reload so that the user can continue reading just where he started. Otherwise please specify what else you would like to achieve.

Comment: I wanted to know if there is any other way?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `anchors`, you can even have a url pointing to a specific loction on the site. If you reload the page you end up at the same position. So make the url auto update from elements on your page. But you MUST remove all anchor tags on page load, if you dont do that the scroll will snapp and lag to the anchors

```js
var url = "";
    var anchor = "";
    var element1 = "";
    var element2 = "";    
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //save url on page load        
        $('a').each(function () {
            //get the anchor name attribute
            var nameAttr = $(this).attr('name');
            if (nameAttr !== undefined) {             
                //remove special characters and replace space with "-" on name attribute
                nameAttr = nameAttr.replace(/\s/g, '-'); 
                nameAttr = nameAttr.replace(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%.'":*?<>{}]/g, '');
                nameAttr = nameAttr.toLocaleLowerCase();
                //changing the name attribute
                $(this).attr('name', nameAttr);
            }            
        });    
        //Storing url
        url = window.location.href;
        url = url.substring(0, url.indexOf('#'));          
    });    
    $(function () {
        $(window).scroll(function () {       
            //retrive right headline
            var findMiddleElement = (function (docElm) {
                var viewportHeight = docElm.clientHeight,                   
                    elements = $('.subheading');
                return function (e) {
                    var middleElement;
                    if (e && e.type === 'resize')
                        viewportHeight = docElm.clientHeight;
                    elements.each(function () {
                        var pos = this.getBoundingClientRect().top;
                        if (pos > viewportHeight / 2.5 && pos < viewportHeight / 1.5) {
                            //find correct element
                            middleElement = this;
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                    //If statement to remove lag
                    element1 = middleElement;
                    if (element1 !== element2) {
                        element2 = element1;
                        anchor = $(middleElement).text();
                        if (anchor !== "") {           
                            //change url
                            //remove special characters and replace space with "-" in url
                            anchor = anchor.replace(/\s/g, '-');
                            anchor = anchor.replace(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%.'":*?<>{}]/g, '');
                            anchor = anchor.toLocaleLowerCase();
                            //update url
                            window.location.href = url + "#" + anchor;                            
                        }                            
                    }                    
                }
            })(document.documentElement);
            $(window).on('scroll resize', findMiddleElement);  
            //remove the url to prevent lag
            $("a").removeAttr('name');
            console.log(window.location.href);
        });
    });
```

```css
p{
margin: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class='subheading'><a name='test1'/>test1</p>
<p class='subheading'><a name='test2'/>test2</p>
<p class='subheading'><a name='test3'/>test3</p>
<p class='subheading'><a name='test4'/>test4</p>
<p class='subheading'><a name='test5'/>test5</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can store the position in local storage , after page load you can scroll to that position.