# How can I keep the position inside a scrollable list when I add new elements to the top?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I add some elements to my scrollable list with jQuery's `prepend()` function and I'm initially at the top of the list, the list automatically scrolls to the top of the first added element and doesn't keep the position. How can I prevent this?

This is my code example showing my problem:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("button").click(function() {
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].forEach(function() {
      $("div").prepend("<span class='new'></span>");
    });
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 200px;
  height: 350px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

span {
  height: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
  background: gray;
}

span.new {
  background: red !important;
}

span:nth-child(odd) {
  background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
<button>Prepend elements</button>
```

Comment: Your snippet does not demonstrate the behaviour you describe. If you scroll down before clicking the button the scroll position remains the same

Comment: Yes, but without scrolling first. This case is my problem.

Comment: Your 'problem' is "How to scroll to bottom"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scroll to bottom of div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270612/scroll-to-bottom-of-div)

Comment: @Wimanicesir I don't think so. Probably more like "How to keep the position"

Comment: @Wimanicesir No, it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Well technically the scroll position did not change when you are at the top. Because after you add the items, it is still at the top. You would need to get the position of the initial first item, then scroll to it but then you would need to decide where the "first" item is before adding and what item qualifies as first when user scrolls that list

Comment: @Huangism I know but this will be always 0 and when I add new items and scroll to 0, I'm going the wrong way I think

Comment: @Mr.Jo maybe the behaviour you are looking for is - before adding items, get position of the scroll, then, after adding items, get height of added items, and then scroll to the sum of original scroll position and the height of the added item so you are at where you were

Comment: @Huangism Sounds complicated. Do you have an idea how to start with this in the code? Because I can't work with the list at all I think (position offset().top is 0)

Comment: @Mr.Jo not that complicated, breaking it down, there is get height of added elements(jquery height()) and for position of scrolled element https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481350/how-to-get-scrollbar-position-with-javascript

Comment: @Huangism But what if the elements have different heights?

Comment: @Mr.Jo doesn't matter the height is calculated on each item, we are not using the 40. In chrome, when you add items, the scroll position remains the same as before, the styles of the odd and even rows kind fo throws you off but if you are at second item from the top before adding, you are still there after adding, but because your row colour changed due to the addition, it looks like it moved. You can clearly see this if you add text to the spans

Comment: @Mr.Jo see the answer, it is an easier way to do the same thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to maintain the scroll position you can track the scrollTop position and scrollHeight of the div then use scrollTop – like:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("button").click(function() {
    let $div = $("div");
    let top = $div.scrollTop();
    let scrollHeight = $div.prop("scrollHeight");
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].forEach(function() {
      $div.prepend("<span class='new'></span>")
    });
    $div.scrollTop(top + $div.prop("scrollHeight") - scrollHeight);
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 200px;
  height: 350px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

span {
  height: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
  background: gray;
}

span.new {
  background: red !important;
}

span:nth-child(odd) {
  background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
<button>Prepend elements</button>
```

Comment: I love this! Thank you so much for your help. Now I learned something new.

Comment: Never prepend to DOM inside loops. Concatenate inside loops - and than prepend only once, after the loop.

Comment: I think it was only intended as an example of many items being added (you're right though :-)