# Making on-scroll style changes using vanilla js

Tags: javascript

I want remove `.bg-light` from nav element at 400px and more scrolls

```
<nav id="my-nav" class="bg-light navbar text-info"> change my background color</nav>
```

I know it's an easy task with jQuery but is it possible to do it with vanilla js?

Thanks for spending time on my question I will be glad to see opinion

Comment: Do any of the [answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481350/how-to-get-scrollbar-position-with-javascript) help? (Or try one of [these](https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-get-scroll-position-element/) [tutorials](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-the-position-of-scrollbar-using-javascript/?ref=lbp).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we start by grabbing the "nav" element using the ID.
Then setting our Y-axis's offset.
Attach a listener to the window object.
On scroll, compare the current position to our desired offset.

```
const navBar = document.getElementById("my-nav");

const offset = 400;

window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    if (window.scrollY >= offset){
        navBar.classList.remove("bg-light")
    } else {
        navBar.classList.add("bg-light")
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its possible with Vanilla JavaScript, use the "scroll" event handler to get the info. As the users moves through the site it will return the Y axis position in pixels. By using an if statement remove or add the `bg-light` class, like so:

```js
let nav = document.getElementById("my-nav");

window.addEventListener("scroll", (e) => { 

  if(this.scrollY > 400){ nav.classList.remove('bg-light') }
  else{
    nav.classList.add('bg-light')
  }

});
```

```css
*{padding:5px}
html{height:3000px;font-size:20px}
.bg-light{background-color: #F8F8F8!important; color:black!important;}
.navbar{position:fixed;background-color:blue; color:white;}
```

```html
<nav id="my-nav" class="bg-light navbar text-info"> Change my background color at scrollY 400px</nav>
```