# change scroll from vertical to horizontal automatically when section comes in view

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-animations, react-animations

I am want to create a react site where while scroll when I get to services section page should change from vertical scroll to horizontal scroll for that section. Any idea how can I achieve this?

Comment: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example?? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: This is a good question but you should show your code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use framer-motion: https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-horizontal-scroll-by-scrolling-vertically-forked-473s1?file=/src/SmoothScroll.js

Framer-motion uses "ghost" div. Height of that div is equal to the slider length, you scroll it and framer create horizontal scrolling. It also check's when your slider is in a viewport.

Answer (score 0):

[How to get scrollbar position with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481350/how-to-get-scrollbar-position-with-javascript)

this might help you if you got scroll position and add a condition on scroll

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).