# Need a javascript function to gradually resize the logo on scroll position

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking to gradually resize a logo on scroll position using Vanilla JS.

- Cannot use CSS in a stylesheet
- No use of jQuery
- Must gradually resize with scroll not all at once at a certain position.
- Use percentage.
- At 0px scroll position = 100%  then if  > 0px scroll position then percent width decreases.
- Logo not ever smaller than 50% Do not use css “max-width”.
- The javascript function should not continue to decrease the size on
  scroll after 50%.

For some reason, I have not been able to find any question that is doing this exactly but seems like a common need for websites that have a sticky header and need to decrease the logo size but not suddenly using a CSS class added via JS.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a common requirement to me - I think most use a CSS animation or something similar on resize, but I've never heard of it on scroll

Comment: Yes, I use CSS animation mostly but I feel it will be much smoother if it is tied to the user's scroll position.

Comment: So, how big is the logo if you're trying to do it on scroll?

Comment: The logo is top left and about 300px wide in the header looking to size it down to 150px on scroll.

Comment: 300px is quite wide - any particular reason why it needs to be so big on page load? Either way, I don't know if there's even a worthwhile way of getting it to smoothly resize on scroll.

Comment: There are plenty of sites that have a 300px wide logo. Also, plenty of sites have animations tied to the scroll position. I guess I'll touch upon my JS skills and post the solution ‍♂️

Comment: Not sure if this one helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69071143/13168911