# Is there a better way to determine whether a container has finished scrolling in either direction?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, scroll

I'm currently using a simple calculation to determine whether a container has finished scrolling by adding the (length of the scrollbar thumb + translateX of the scrollbar thumb) and looking at whether that equals to the length of the track. I know the typical method involves scrollRight/scrollWidth/clientWidth but either way I run into inconsistencies depending on the resolution (zooming in/out of the browser), where pixel amounts are no longer integers and are off by like 0-1.0 pixels.

The simple fix I've tried would be to add some sort of range threshold of plus or minus 1-2 pixels but this does not seem like a solution where I'm certain it'll work on every resolution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481350/how-can-i-get-the-scrollbar-position-with-javascript

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.