# How to make chrome extension to save scroll position?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension, manifest

I'm trying to make an extension to get the scroll position of a website and save it for later (i know this already exist but I mostly want to know how it works). The thing is that I don't understand how to do it, does anyone know a website with a tuto about it, or a github repo, i mean anything that could help me? Thanks!

Comment: [Get scroll position like this in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481350/how-can-i-get-the-scrollbar-position-with-javascript).

Then, run this script inside content script to get the scroll position.
You can save scroll positions for every page to the your own db or local storage its your own preference